# Using angular variable inside MVC razor view

Tags: asp.net-mvc, angularjs, asp.net-mvc-4

Can someone please tell me how I can use angularJS variable in the below statements. So Instead of scenario.InterestRate I want to add a angular variable {{x.rate}} and in place of scenario.Rate I want {{x.flat}}

```
<td class="text-right">
                    @String.Format("{0:F4}", scenario.InterestRate)
                </td>
              @if (scenario.Rate != null)
```

Thanks

Comment: Why do you need 2 templating engines in the first place? Your server code and angular variables are not interchangeable...they run in completely different environments and at different times. What exactly are you trying to accomplish?

Answer (score 2):

What you're trying to do isn't possible.  Razor templates are executed server-side, before they reach the browser -- which is where angular runs.

It looks like your intention is to use razor to format the value coming from angular.  The appropriate way to do this would be to use angular filters, specifically [the number formatter](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/filter/number).

```
<td class="text-right">
    {{x.rate | number:4}}
</td>
```